# angularjs update model based on sum of other fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I want to be able to update a value in my data model based on the result of two other fields.  using

```
<td><input ng-value="s.hours*s.rate"></td>
```

I have no problem calculating the result but how am I able to bind it to toal?

eg I tried

```
<td><input ng-model="s.total" ng-value="s.hours*s.rate"></td>
```

but the model overrides the value here?

See full example

```js
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.staff = [
            {"id": "1","name": "Alex","rate": "10", "hours": "10","total":"0"},
            {"id": "2","name": "Brad","rate": "20", "hours": "10","total":"0"},
            {"id": "3","name": "Cam","rate": "15", "hours": "10","total":"0"}
        ];
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app">
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
              <table>
                <tr><td>name</td><td>rates</td><td>hours</td><td>total</td><td>total</td></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="s in staff">
                    <td>{{s.name}}</td>
                    <td><input  ng-model="s.rate"></td>  
                    <td><input  ng-model="s.hours"></td>
                    <td><input ng-value="s.hours*s.rate"></td>
                  <td><input ng-model="s.total"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can this be acheived?

Comment: several ways to do it with angular, use `ng-change` or `$watch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just fire the calculation on any change of "rate" or "hours".

```
        $scope.calc= function(s) {
             s.total=s.hours*s.rate;   
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.staff, function(s) { $scope.calc(s)});
```

I've put up a fiddle with the code and HTML modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/macl/sx3zouuv/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* ways to accomplish this.  Here is a simple loop that updates the `total` property whenever the list changes:

```
$scope.$watch('staff'. function(newVal, oldVal) {
  angular.forEach(newVal, function(s) {
    s.total = s.rate * s.hours;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably replace this in your snippet:

`<input ng-model="s.total">`

with:

`{{ total(s) }}`

Then within your controller:

`$scope.total = function (staffmember) { return staffmember.rate * staffmember.hours; }`

Remember that you may always embed function calls within AngularJS expressions to clean up your code and you may expose functions on your scope for such use.